# Approximate distribution of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-X_{2i-1})$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[Question:](https://prnt.sc/wiqf6o)
Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $E(X_i)=1$ and $Var(Xi)=1;,i=1,2,3....$Then the approximate distribution of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-X_{2i-1})$ for large n is:

$(A) ܰN(0,1)$

$(B)N(0,2)$ ܰ

$(C)N(0,0.5)$

$(D)N(0,0.25)$

$$\text{My attempt}$$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-X_{2i-1})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}((X_{2}-X_{1})+(X_{4}-X_{3})+(X_{6}-X_{5})+....)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(-X_{1}+X_{2}-X_{3}+X_{4}-X_{5}...) $

Seeing options I didn't calculate the mean. So trying to calculate variance.

$\frac{1}{n}V(-X_{1}+X_{2}-X_{3}+X_{4}-X_{5}...)=\frac{1}{n}\bigg(V(X_{1})+V(X_{2})+V(X_{3})+V(X_{4})+V(X_{5}...)\bigg)=\frac{n}{n}=1$

So it follows $N(0,1)$

**But the answer is B. I don't know what's my mistake here plus different ways of solving this problem if you could tell me that will wide my way of thinking to solve these kinds of problems.**

Thanks.

Comment: There are $2n$ terms in the numerator of variance.

Comment: How? Could you please prove it.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I got it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $X_{2i}-X_{2i-1}$ are independent so it is easy to find the variance of $\frac 1  {\sqrt n} (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_{2i}-X_{2i-1})$: It is $\frac 1 n (n\, var (X_{2i}-X_{2i-1}))$ or $2$.